# React useState hook is running indefinitely - infinite loop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have a simple react functional component.

The code should be self-explanatory. If the status is equal to 'some status', go to a URL, fetch some information, and set the state of the component to the information that has been fetched. On the return () just display the information. Everything works fine, the id of the data is displayed. However, when I open the dev tools and do the inspection, the console.log("data"+data.id); is run indefinitely. I wonder what is making it run indefinitely.

if I remove the change data(data) from inside the fetch, the console.log does not run indefinitely.

I am scratching my head as to why, changing the status would make the code enter in an infinite loop?

```
function ReturnInfo(props) {
var currentstatus = props.currentstatus; // receiving the current status as prop from parent.

const [data, changeData] = useState({});
let { slug } = useParams(); // getting the slug.


if (currentstatus == 'some status') {
    fetch(`https:someurl/${slug}`).
        then(res => res.json()).
        then(data => {
            console.log("data" + data.id);
            changeData(data);
        });



    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {data.id}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


else {
    return (
        <p>try harder!</p>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should use `useEffect`, The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components:
useEffect docs = https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

And if you don't add the dependency array it will run on each update.
Simple wrap your side-effect/async task code within the useEffect function.
And add the dependency array. add empty array if you want to run it only once.

```
 useEffect(() => {
 fetch(`https:someurl/${slug}`).
        then(res => res.json()).
        then(data => {
            console.log("data" + data.id);
            changeData(data);
        });
    }, [slug])
```

It will stop the unnecessary rerender.

**Edit** Try this

```js
function ReturnInfo(props) {
var currentstatus = props.currentstatus; // receiving the current status as prop from parent.

const [data, changeData] = useState({});
let { slug } = useParams(); // getting the slug.


useEffect(() => {
 fetch(`https:someurl/${slug}`).
        then(res => res.json()).
        then(data => {
            console.log("data" + data.id);
            changeData(data);
        });
}, [slug])

if (currentstatus === 'some status') {
   return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {data.id}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
} 
    return <p>try harder!</p>
}
```

Comment: It does not work. as every time changedata(data) is encountered, useEffect() is called and you get in the situation of infinite loop again! i have tried the code you suggested. it has the same issue if the infinite loop of console.log.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function every time the component is rendered. The function gets called, it updates the state, and makes the component to re-render.

You should call the function when an event occurrs or change the currentstatus value every time the block is executed.

Answer (score 0):

changeData(data) will cause reevaluation of the component. Which leads to call fetch again, which make infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() {
if (currentstatus == 'some status') {
fetch(`https:someurl/${slug}`).
    then(res => res.json()).
    then(data => {
        console.log("data" + data.id);
        changeData(data);
    });
```

}},[])

Comment: It does not work. as every time changedata(data) is encountered, useEffect() is called and you get in the situation of infinite loop again! i have tried the code you suggested. it has the same issue if the infinite loop of console.log

Comment: Whether you provide data as dependency in useEffect?